# In Freemarker - how do I get the first value in a map

Tags: freemarker

in Java I would do something like this:

```
map.values().iterator().next();
```

How do you do it in Freemarker? something like this?

```
${map?values?first()}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
${map?values[0]}
```

Or if you are not sure that the map is not empty:

```
${map?values[0]!someDefault}
```